# Hive - Jdbc vs Thrift client - which one to use?

Tags: jdbc, hive

Which one would be the preferred client - JDBC or Thrift - for connecting to Hive through Java? Or are they the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both going through thrift server. so underneath it doesn't make that much difference. Just JDBC gives you sql like query ability.

Comment: does this answer still hold for the latest hive versions like hive3+ ?